# how to sort pandas dataframe on multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe

```
 Code     Date         Tank       Hourly_bucket
 0        2018-08-01   1          00:00:01 - 00:30:00
 7        2018-08-02   1          08:00:01 - 08:30:00
 8        2018-08-02   1          09:00:00 - 09:30:00
 1        2018-08-01   1          04:30:01 - 05:00:00
 2        2018-08-01   2          01:00:01 - 01:30:00
 5        2018-08-01   2          10:00:01 - 10:30:00
 6        2018-08-01   2          11:00:01 - 11:30:00
```

I want to arrange the dataframe by `Date,Tank and Hourly_bucket` Following is my desired dataframe

```
 Code     Date         Tank       Hourly_bucket
 0        2018-08-01   1          00:00:01 - 00:30:00
 1        2018-08-01   1          04:30:01 - 05:00:00
 2        2018-08-01   2          01:00:01 - 01:30:00
 5        2018-08-01   2          10:00:01 - 10:30:00
 7        2018-08-01   2          11:00:01 - 11:30:00 
 4        2018-08-02   1          00:00:00 - 00:30:00
 8        2018-08-02   1          08:00:01 - 08:30:00
```

I have tried

```
df.sort_values(['Tank','Hourly_bucket','Date'], ascending = True)
```

But,it does not give me desired output.

Comment: Which column do you want to sort? You can only sort 1 column at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to enshure that df.Date and df.Hourly_bucket are dealt as datetime Series. 
Then you have to set inplace = True otherwise, the modifications won't be save.

```
df.Hourly_bucket = df.Hourly_bucket.str.slice(0, 8)
df.Hourly_bucket = pd.to_datetime(df.Hourly_bucket)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df.sort_values(['Date', 'Tank','Hourly_bucket'], ascending =True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

```
df = df.sort_values(“Hourly_bucket”).sort_values(“Tank”).sort_values(“Date”)
```